# A-Frame vive-controls: Get position on the trackpad

Tags: aframe, htc-vive

is it possible to get more information about the trackpad? I want to make an app that rotates the loaded model depending on where the user clicks on the trackpad, therefore I need the position. Could not find anything in the docs.
Is this possible or will it be possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the axis at `el.components['tracked-controls'].axis` or listen to `axismove` event `el.addEventListener('axismove', evt => { console.log(evt); });`

https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/tracked-controls.html#events_axismove